# Pandas dataframe- Drop missing value rows or replace missing values with 0 based on condition

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with some missing values in column A.I have noticed that column A values are missing when column B values are 0 as below:

```
B   A
-----
10  100
0   NULL
20  500
0   NULL
```

I want to write code in python based on the logic below:

```
IF df[A] isnull then 
 if df[B]==0  then
    replace df[A] with 0
 else
    drop df[A] row
END IF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
# Code to create input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [10, 0, 20, 0, 1], 'A': [100, np.nan, 500, np.nan, np.nan]})

# Input dataframe
    B      A
0  10  100.0
1   0    NaN
2  20  500.0
3   0    NaN
4   1    NaN

# Code to solve your problem
df.drop(index=df[df['A'].isnull() & df['B'] != 0].index, inplace=True)
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(0)

# Output dataframe
    B      A
0  10  100.0
1   0    0.0
2  20  500.0
3   0    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks,your solution solved my probelm.if you dont mind ,can you please explain what this code do?df.drop(index=df[df['A'].isnull() & df['B'] != 0].index, inplace=True)

Comment: `df[df['A'].isnull() & df['B'] != 0]` gives the filtered rows that you want to drop based on your one of the condition i.e column `A` is `NaN` and column `B` is `not 0`. And then you get index of these rows which is needed as input to `pd.drop`. For your another condition, the second line selects column `A` and fills `NaN` with `0`. Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: @Nand.Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I made a special case like B not equal to 0 and A is `NaN`

***Sample Data***

```
df
Out[563]: 
    B      A
0  10  100.0
1   0    NaN
2  20  500.0
3   0    NaN
4   1    NaN
```

---

```
newdf=df[~(df.B.ne(0)&df.A.isna())].copy()
newdf.A=newdf.A.fillna(0)
newdf
Out[566]: 
    B      A
0  10  100.0
1   0    0.0
2  20  500.0
3   0    0.0
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer. but i dont want to copy and create a new dataframe